# Flip ordering of legend without altering ordering in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have found that when adding `coord_flip()` to certain plots using ggplot2 that the order of values in the legend no longer lines up with the order of values in the plot.

For example:

```
dTbl = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                  y=c('a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b'),
                  z=c('q','q','q','q','r','r','r','r'))

print(ggplot(dTbl, aes(x=factor(y),y=x, fill=z)) +
      geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat='identity') +
      coord_flip() +
      theme(legend.position='top', legend.direction='vertical'))
```

[image]

I would like the 'q' and 'r' in the legend to be reversed without changing the order of 'q' and 'r' in the plot.

`scale.x.reverse()` looked promising, but it doesn't seem to work within factors (as is the case for this bar plot).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're looking for `guides`:

```
ggplot(dTbl, aes(x=factor(y),y=x, fill=z)) +
      geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat='identity') +
      coord_flip() +
      theme(legend.position='top', legend.direction='vertical') + 
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

I was reminded in chat by Brian that there *is* a more general way to do this for arbitrary orderings, by setting the `breaks` argument:

```
ggplot(dTbl, aes(x=factor(y),y=x, fill=z)) +
      geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat='identity') +
      coord_flip() +
      theme(legend.position='top', legend.direction='vertical') + 
      scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("r","q"))
```

Comment: +1, clearly the better answer, but still keeping the other for curiosity's sake.

Comment: This works just fine exclusively to reverse order of levels label but we cannot reorder arbitrarily levels.

Comment: @PauloCardoso Good to point out, but that wasn't needed here, as the labels will either be reversed or not reversed (most likely) when messing with coord_flip()

Comment: @PauloCardoso Indeed. I seem to recall having struggled with that general problem in the past. AFAIK there isn't a great general solution (i.e. arbitrary ordering of legend values, independent of what's displayed in the plot).

Comment: @joran Thanks! This is something I've never used. Do it already saves us manipulating factor levels order? Nice!

Comment: Just to add, the  `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("r","q"))` takes the labels and not the factor levels.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like joran's elegant answer, you can go with the hack:

```
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(-.9), stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary level reordering, you can modify the order of `levels` in the `factor`:

```
dTbl$z=factor(dTbl$z,levels=c('r','q'))
ggplot(dTbl, aes(x=factor(y),y=x, fill=z)) +
       geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat='identity') +
       coord_flip() +
       theme(legend.position='top', legend.direction='vertical')
```

Comment: Be sure to note that this reverses the order in which the levels are displayed in the graph as well.

Comment: @Joran answered the specific question but this was exactly what I was thinking as a more flexible option. =)

Comment: This may not solve the problem because whatever the arbitrary level order before using ggplot(), once coord_flip() is applied, the order of bars/lines in the plot still becomes the reverse of what is in the legend.