# Rearrange stacked barplot legend labels without changing plot (and fix tick marks) in R

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

Is there a way to change the order of factor levels in a stacked barplot legend without changing the order of the plot too (and without mislabeling the data)? I'd like to change the order to "Presence" first, then "Absence".

I'm also having trouble with the tick marks being slightly shifted to one side.

```
dput(prop)
structure(list(WYR = c(2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), CYR = c(2005L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), class = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("prop_zero", 
"prop_nonzero"), class = "factor"), proportions = c(0.170212765957447, 
0.829787234042553, 0.170212765957447, 0.829787234042553, 0.361702127659574, 
0.638297872340426, 0.234042553191489, 0.765957446808511, 0.234042553191489, 
0.765957446808511, 0.434782608695652, 0.565217391304348, 0.58695652173913, 
0.41304347826087, 0.574468085106383, 0.425531914893617, 0.51063829787234, 
0.48936170212766, 0.595744680851064, 0.404255319148936, 0.608695652173913, 
0.391304347826087, 0.51063829787234, 0.48936170212766, 0.404255319148936, 
0.595744680851064, 0.319148936170213, 0.680851063829787, 0.468085106382979, 
0.531914893617021, 0.608695652173913, 0.391304347826087)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(prop, aes(x = CYR, y = proportions, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey70", "grey20"), labels = c("Absence", "Presence")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.0), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = years, labels = ~ rep("", length(.x))) +
  # CYR labels
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = prop$CYR,
    y = -Inf,
    label = prop$CYR,
    size = 6.5 / .pt,
    vjust = 2.5
  ) +
  # WYR labels
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = prop$CYR,
    y = -Inf,
    label = prop$WYR,
    size = 6.5 / .pt,
    vjust = 4,
    color = "grey"
  ) +
  # CYR title
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = -Inf,
    y = -Inf,
    label = c("CYR"),
    vjust = 2.5, hjust = 1,
    size = 6.5 / .pt
  ) +
  # WYR title
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = -Inf,
    y = -Inf,
    label = c("WYR"),
    vjust = 4, hjust = 1,
    size = 6.5 / .pt,
    color = "grey") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(margin = margin(t = 8.8, b = 8.8)),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0), size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1), 
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1), 
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(y = "% presence/absence") +
  ggtitle("DRY SEASONS")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing your fill argument in the aes from `class` to `fct_rev(class)`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that just changes which factor level gets plotted first. The legend then becomes incorrect (colors and labels don't match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here!: [Flip ordering of legend without altering ordering in plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517002/flip-ordering-of-legend-without-altering-ordering-in-plot)

Just add this code to the end of the ggplot: `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`