# How to reverse the legend ramp color in ggplot2 raster graph, without changing the assigned colors to the variables with scale_fill_viridis_d?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, reverse, viridis

I have tried unsuccessfully to reverse the direction of the legend color ramp in a `ggplot2` raster graph. I want the temperature ranges to be ordered from highest to lowest without changing the color assignment of the variable.

The dataframe was built from a raster: `EneroT5cmSC`

```
datene <- as.data.frame(EneroT5cmSC,xy=TRUE)%>%drop_na()
datene$cuts <- cut(datene$layer, breaks=seq(21, 29, length.out=12))
```

ggplot2 code:

```
p1 <-ggplot()+
     geom_raster(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=cuts),data=datene_stuc)+
     geom_sf(fill='transparent',data=conturu)+
     geom_sf(fill='transparent',data=locuru)+
     scale_fill_viridis_d( option = "B", 'Temp (Cº)')+
     theme_minimal()+
     theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
           axis.title.y=element_blank())+
     labs(title="Soil Temperature at 5cm depth",
          subtitle='January',
          caption='Fagro, 2022')
```

Graph:

[Legend in reverse direction with correct color assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyIo7.png)

dput:

```
datene_stuc <-
structure(
list(
  x = c(-57.063098328,-57.021448328,-56.996458328,-56.988128328),
  y = c(-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664,-30.087481664),
  layer = c(
    25.6227328470624,
    26.6386584334308,
    26.0636709134397,
    26.0580615984563
  ),
  cuts = structure(
    c(7L, 9L,
      8L, 8L),
    .Label = c(
      "(20,20.8]",
      "(20.8,21.6]",
      "(21.6,22.5]",
      "(22.5,23.3]",
      "(23.3,24.1]",
      "(24.1,24.9]",
      "(24.9,25.7]",
      "(25.7,26.5]",
      "(26.5,27.4]",
      "(27.4,28.2]",
      "(28.2,29]"
    ),
    class = "factor"
  )
),
row.names = c(NA,
              4L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Set **direction = -1** in **scale_fill_viridis()**.

Comment: Unfortunately direction = -1 changes the mapping of colors to temperature ranges. I do not want that. I want it to change the order only in the legend. Thank you Stéphane

Comment: Maybe see this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517002/flip-ordering-of-legend-without-altering-ordering-in-plot

Comment: After many tries, I restarted rstudio and now **guides (fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))** works perfectly. @MrFlick Thank you very much for your suggestion, problem solved.